# Как реализовать анимацию типа Parallax эффекта?

Tags: android

Имеется RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

и item

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Подскажите как можно сделать чтобы при скролинге при подходе к центру экрана из под TextView выезжал ImageView ? Подскажите ссылкой на пример или мб есть библиотека... или что то похожее....

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться одной из [библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Parallax%20android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults), можно самому сделать:

```
    scrollView.setOnScrollListener(new ParallaxScrollView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(header, scrollY / 1.5f); //двигаем header в полтора раза медленнее.
        }
    });
```

Метод `ViewHelper.setTranslationY` из библиотеки [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids), используется для того, что бы анимировать вью в API9, в более высоких версиях это делается из коробки.

Comment: Эти библиотеки работают с header а мне нужно чтобы анимация была в item

Comment: @qwend, тогда не очень понятно какого вы хотите добиться эффекта